# I am installing a Honeywell Pro 2000

Tags: wiring, hvac, thermostat

So, I have the green, white, blue and red wires coming in, but DO NOT have a yellow. There is a brown. I do have both regular gas heat, and AC. What terminal should the brown wire go? And should the red wire be hooked up to the R terminal or the RC terminal. Or should it be hooked to one, with a jumper. I have no way to get to my furnace, as it's an apartment. It's in a locked space between the two units. And no, I wasn't smart enough to trace where every wire went to the old manual White Rogers Square dumb box.. I DO have heat, that kicks on and works fine as intended... but the AC will not come on. HELLLPP!~! Yes it's could out, but it still should kick on right? The house is 70 degrees, so If i set it to cool 68 deg, It should come on... Thank you for any help today or soon!!!

Chad

Comment: I need to add, that the red wire was NOT hooked up to the old thermostat, and was tucked in the space behind the thermostat. Is this a wire that will send 24 volts to the new battery OR hard wired thermostat?? Im just needing some help here... LOL Please Advise!!!

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring at both the furnace and thermostat ends, as well as the wiring diagram for your furnace?

Comment: I can at the thermostat end, but not at the furnace. That is in a locked are between the apartments...